How to convert instance of "any" to text?
We have a requirement where we are expected to maintain the internal audit of requests/errors etc.
To do this, I have written the function as below:
async function createAuditRecordInternal(ctx: ReqContext, sourcefile: string, messagetype: string, message: any) {}

Here, "message" is of type any. It is done because it can accept instance of Request/Error/any custom type defined in our code.
In Oracle table, I have column of "CLOB" type to save the details that are sent in message.
const msg: OracleDB.BindParameter = {
    dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN,
    val: String(message),
    type: OracleDB.STRING,
};

However, while logging the incoming request from postman OR instance of any custom type in Oracle column, I see [object Object].
Error caught in try-catch is inserted in db column as text.
Is there any way to convert the contents coming in "message" to text always?


Node Version: 21.7.3
Express: 4.19.2
OracleDB: 6.5.0


JSON.stringify is a good starting point, but it cannot deal with any object - for example it does not support circular references. Do you really need ANY object, without constraints?

@Lesiak, yes, I also tried JSON.stringify and it failed due to circular dependencies. Unfortunately, 'message' has to be generic.

You can try a library that can deal with circular references like flatted

@Lesiak, I think I found the solution - https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-safe, I will test further and update here.

I believe the package I mentioned is better - it can serialize and deserialize curcular references, while json-stringify-safe returns a placeholder string, which is a one-way transformation
